# NYTProf Profiler for Perl

Tags: perl, devel-nytprof

This question is about `Devel::NYTProf` profiler.

The output that I receive from the profiler for a simple line such as:

```
use strict;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
statements: 3 
Time on Line: 22µs
Calls: 2
Time in Sub: 12µs
```

**So my questions are:**

1. How is this 3 statements ?
2. The time in sub .. what does this represent ?
3. Does this represent the time spent converting this
       module into optree  or is this something else?
4. Is this compile phase time or run phase time ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

```
use Foo;
```

is equivalent to executing

```
require Foo;
Foo->import;
```

at compile time. So perhaps the sub that was called is `strict::import`.

**Update**: profiling the program

```
require strict;
strict->import;
```

shows that `Devel::NYTProf` counts the `require` statement as one sub call and `import` as another.